# Division button for Win32 app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I'm coding in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and when I add this code into my code everything blows up. I'm trying to make a calculator and this segment of code is the code for my "division button". Can you help me?

When I add this, 10 build errors show up:

```
private: System::Void button13_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
firstnum = Convert::ToInt32(lblDisplay->Text);
lblDisplay->="0";
operation='/';

}
```

Comment: That is not c++ and it is not winapi. Would you care to describe the problem better than "everything blows up?"

Comment: I believe that's C++/CLI. You mean just adding that code causes your program to "blow up"? Or do you have to press the button for a problem to occur? Or do you get a compile error? Are you sure that `lblDisplay->="0"` is valid syntax? Looks suspicious to me.

Comment: When I add this, 10 build errors show up :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBBe9oKU7jk I only followed the instructions.

Comment: @Afel: "*When I add this, 10 build errors show up*" - when you ask for help regarding errors, always show the actual error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `lblDisplay->Text = "0";` instead of `lblDisplay->="0";`